# JAVA-BUCLE Generar números pares aleatorios del 0 al 100 y que no acabe hasta sacar el número 24

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles, while, java-8

Buenas pues como formulo en la pregunta esa es mi gran duda. El contador no funciona bien y también hay veces que al compilar no me saca el número 24 y se acaba el bucle, podrían ayudarme?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Realiza un programa que genere números aleatorios pares del 0 al 100 y que no acabe hasta"
        + "que no saque el número 24. El programa tendrá que decir cuantos números se han generado.");

        int contador = 1;

        for (int i = 1 ; i!=24 ; i++){
            

            int aleatorio = (int)(Math.random() * (100 + 1));

            i=aleatorio;
            contador++;
            if(i%2==0){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(i==24){
                System.out.println("Lo hemos intentado " + contador + " veces");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask]. ¿Qué significa *números parejos del 0 al 100*?

Comment: Buenas, perdona por ponerlo en otro idioma ya está en español. A lo otro no entiendo a qué se refiere. El código así se puede compilar perfectamente, un saludo y gracias.

Comment: @ZzCry a que te refieres con "Numeros parejos del 0 al 100 ??

Comment: @Excorpion Numeros pares del 0 al 100. 2,4,6,8 ...

Comment: Entiendo, numeros parejos no es lo mismo que numeros pares. Por eso la confusion.

Comment: Estás usando la estructura de control equivocada. No necesitas contar 24 iteraciones sino que lo haga mientras sea necesario... `while algo sea true` y contar y comprobar hasta que salga el 24 en el generador, cambiar el algo a false y chán

Comment: He dejado una respuesta completa, explicando el error en tu procedimiento, y dejandote una solución.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procederé a explicar tu error y luego solucionarlo.

Tome un poco tu código y lo corregí un tanto, **pero fue solo para encontrar el error**

El problema que tienes, es COMO estas usando el FOR.

Los FOR, tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
for( Inicializacion ; Condición; incrementar/reducir){ 
    ....
}
```

Al momento de dar una condición de `i!=24` es donde estás fallando !!!
Al momento de `i` ser igual a 23, se produce un `i++`, aumentando, por ende, el valo0r de i en 1, haciendo que `i=24` y deteniendo el for.

Por eso es que el codigo se detiene.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ahora, la solución es la siguiente: EL USO DE UN DO-WHILE

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Realiza un programa que genere números aleatorios pares del 0 al 100 y que no acabe hasta"
        + "que no saque el número 24. El programa tendrá que decir cuantos números se han generado.");
        int contador = 1;
        int i = 0;
        do{
            int aleatorio = (int)(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
            i=aleatorio;
            if(i%2==0){
                System.out.println(i);
                if(i==24){
                    System.out.println("Lo hemos intentado " + contador + " veces");
                    break;
                }
                contador++;
            }
        }while(i!=24);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a la respuesta.

Comment: Si te sirve la respuesta, por favor dale +1 y marcala como respuesta aceptada ;)

Comment: Ahora tengo una pregunta más, más que pregunta una duda. ¿Por qué tenemos que definir la variable i=aleatorio; y no podemos poner simplemente la variable aleatorio dentro del if?, lo he probado y solo sale 0, a qué se debe eso?

Comment: @ZzCry acabo de notar un problema en la logica. El texto dice "generar números aleatorios pares", pero acá estás generando CUALQUIER numero entre 0 y 100.

Comment: @ZzCry Respecto a `aleatorio`, pense que lo estabas haciendo por temas de comodidad, usar solo 1 letra en vez de la palabra. Pero si, si puedes usar `aleatorio` completamente.

Comment: Tienes razón en lo de generar números pares intentaré solucionarlo por mi mismo dado que la gran duda que tenía era porqué no me sacaba los números aleatorios y sí, era por el "for", muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Encontré esto como solucion .> `Genera los numeros aleatorios entre 0 y 50 y multiplicalos por 2`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos, recuerda darme +1 por toda esa ayuda ;)